# Html Regex leaves string unchanged

Tags: regex, scala

I'd like to remove some tags and the content of those tags in a html string like this:

```
val htmlString = "<html><b>test,test</b></html>"
val strippedStr = htmlString.replaceAll("<b[^>]*>[a-z]*<//b>", "")
```

But it seems to leave the string unchanged.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in particular ? (Maybe wrong escaping?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The middle segment of your regex: `[a-z]*`, doesn't allow for commas, so it doesn't match `test,test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape character is `\`, not `/`, and `/` does not need to be escaped in first place. This is not matching because there's no `<//b>` in the input.

Aside from that... do not use regex to manipulate HTML. Use a proper HTML parser, with an HTML sanitizer to pre-process the input.

Comment: Indeed - see [the most renowned answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not an issue, you can use a lazy quantifier to match everything up to `</b>`.  The extra `//` is unnecessary as well.

```
<b[^>]*>.*?</b>
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/yimtpj)

**Your Code**

```
val htmlString = "<html><b>test,test</b></html>"
val strippedStr = htmlString.replaceAll("<b[^>]*>.*?</b>", "")
```